# Why does Artik5 Ubuntu Server image skip installation and go straight to login?

Tags: server, system-installation, samsung

I have followed the instructions for installing the ubuntu server onto an Artik 5 board here:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/artik-5-10
(I'm not installing the Ubuntu Core)

However when I boot from the SD card it doesn't go through the installation process for language, WiFi, user setup etc, instead it boots straight to the login screen. I've tried re-flashing the image and rebooting multiple times. What determines whether the image carries out an installation or just boots normally to the login screen?

I'm using the Artik 520 dev board with a SanDisk Extreme 32GB card. I flashed the Artik 5 image using Etcher and the validation passed. Both switches are definitely set to on. I've tried Googling it to see if there's a default login but haven't found anything and am now a bit stuck. I'm happy to provide any other relevant info.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is booting from the SD card.
I guess it is booting from eMMC.
Try root/root as the login.

I have successfully booted UCore on Raspberry Pi B and B+, but cant seem to get it to boot on a Seeed Eagleye530 or Samsung Artik 5 development kit.